# How to change padding when row change number of columns?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, grid

I have two elements (inputs) with fix size. These two elements are each in it's own column. I need change padding of columns when display is so small that each column is in new line.
I prefer bootstrap solution. 
Is there any someting like this?:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col pr-0">
  ...
```

Here is example of my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <!-- some element of fix size (input) here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <!-- some element of fix size  (input) here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to achieve:
columns in one line - padding=0px; columns in two lines - padding=15px

Comment: do you want to show both column on separate line??

Comment: Based on responsive behavior (depending on display size), second column "jump" on new row automatically. I don't want to change this behavior. Just need to change padding when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="col">
    <!-- some element of fix size (input) here -->
  </div>
    <!-- based on breakpoint add { sm, md, or other } -->
  <div class="col-auto p-y-sm-3">
    <!-- some element of fix size  (input) here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[check this documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 0):

In this example with `.px-sm-2` you will have 2rem padding on X axis on device larger than ≥576px, if not you will have 0 padding. (based on breakpoint, see [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/))

```
<div class="col-auto px-0 px-sm-0">
   <!-- some element of fix size  (input) here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the bootstrap docs for padding. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

You should be able to use the p class like the col class in the following manner:
{property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, and xl.

For example, if you want zero left padding for medium screen your class would be pl-md-0